# Create hyperlink in table using php with sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hyperlink

I'm sorry if this is unclear or difficult to understand, but explaining what I am attempting to do isn't that easy over text. I am trying to create a table of data for a book review site, however I want the title of the post to be a hyperlink to a section for comments for just that post (ID specific), while still having the name of the hyperlink be the variable of the post title (multiple titles are going to be present). The current problem I am having is that I cannot create this hyperlink (when I try to use it currently I just get a blank page with my header) and I do not know how to link that specific hyperlink to the ID specific post (I'm aware my bookcomments.php?id=id is most likely the issue here, not sure how to fix that) Here is my code currently (un-working).

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

$sSql = "SELECT * FROM timestamp WHERE post_id='".$_GET['id']."'";

$oResult = mysql_query($sSql);

$aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($oResult);
}

function displayRowEdit($fpostid, $lauthor, $posttitle, $booktitle, $post, $datepublished)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> $fpostid </td>";
echo "<td> $lauthor </td>";
echo "<td> <a href="sod73.asu.edu/~pspiotto/BlogTest/bookcomments.php?id=id"> $posttitle</a></td>";
echo "<td> $booktitle </td>";
echo "<td> $post </td>";
echo "<td> $datepublished </td>";
echo "<td> <form action=\"delete.php?id=$fpostid\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=$fpostid />";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"DELETE\" > </form></th>";

echo "<td> <form action=\"update.php?id=$fpostid\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"UPDATE\" > </form></th>";
echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: are you talking about the `delete.php?id=$fpostid` link?

Comment: no the reference I'm talking about is `echo "<td> 
<a href="sod73.asu.edu/~pspiotto/BlogTest/bookcomments.php?id=id"> $posttitle</a></td>";`

Comment: What does phpmyadmin have to do with this?

Comment: It is what I had used to create the tables ex:
`CREATE TABLE timestamp 

(post_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, author VARCHAR(100), post_title VARCHAR(100), book_title VARCHAR(100), post TEXT(100), date_published TIMESTAMP(8), PRIMARY KEY(post_id));`

I didn't know if someone needed to know that so I included it anyway, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So? The table is the same whether you create it with phpmyadmin or mysql.

Comment: As I said, sorry for the confusion. I'm fairly new to PHP and SQL and slightly behind in my classes so I'm trying to catch up fairly quickly, I didn't know what information was necessary to have my question answered so I included everything I could think of.

Comment: Does your query return the ID of the book that the review is about? You need to insert that into the URL.

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood what you're commenting on. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the post ID into the URL:

```
echo "<td> <a href='bookcomments.php?id=$fpostid'> $posttitle</a></td>";
```

Also, you have to be careful about the types of quotes you use. Since you're using double quotes for the `echo` argument, you should use single quotes for the HTML attribute parameters (or you need to escape embedded double quotes).

If the `bookcomments.php` script isn't on the same server as the script with the link, you need to use the full URL, like in your version. But when you include a hostname in the URL, you have to put `//` before it, otherwise it's treated as a folder name on the current server.

```
echo "<td> <a href='//sod73.asu.edu/~pspiotto/BlogTest/bookcomments.php?id=$fpostid'> $posttitle</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
echo "<td> <a href="sod73.asu.edu/~pspiotto/BlogTest/bookcomments.php?id=id"> $posttitle</a></td>";
```

to this:

```
 echo "<td> <a href='//sod73.asu.edu/~pspiotto/BlogTest/bookcomments.php?id=$fpostid'> $posttitle</a></td>";
```

Comment: I don't think that URL will work without `//` at the beginning, see the explanation in my answer.

Comment: sorry for that @Barmar... i've changed it now